# TreeView - RelayCommand Does Not Execute Despite Breakpoint Hitting

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, treeview

I have a TreeView with an ItemTemplate/HierarchicalDataTemplate. When I expand a TreeViewItem, I want to trigger a MessageBox. The issue I am currently experiencing is that despite the breakpoint being hit on the `RelayCommand()` in the ViewModel, the actual MessageBox does not execute.

I tried moving the command inside the KeyViewModel itself, and the same behavior occurred.

##### Reproducible Project: https://github.com/MemeMachineSO/TreeViewProblem

[image]

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TreeViewProblem.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TreeViewProblem"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <TreeView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Name="RegistryTreeView" ItemsSource="{Binding Keys}">
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding SubKeys}">
                    <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding name}">
                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Expanded">
                                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ElementName=RegistryTreeView, Path=DataContext.TreeViewItemExpanded}"/>
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    </TreeViewItem>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Just a wild guess : Is It is possible that the main window hides the MessageBox ?

Comment: A second thought , Is the  breakpoint on the instantiation of the RelayCommand object , not the execution.

Comment: @GiladWaisel I tried changing it to another thing, like Environment.Exit(0); and nothing happened

Comment: And the breakpoint does get hit when I press the expand arrow, but interestingly only the first time. Further expansions do nothing

Comment: @MemeMachine: The `MessageBox.Show` method is called when the command is executed. Not when the property getter is invoked...

Comment: @mm8 Too bad there is no way to breakpoint on that eh? Or is there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have set the breakpoint in the getter of the property. The `MessageBox.Show` method is called when the command *executes*. It's not called when the `InvokeCommandAction` binds to the property itself.

Second, the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` is not supposed to contain a `TreeViewItem`. The control creates its own `TreeViewItem` containers and the `Expanded` event of the one in your template is never fired.

Using an `EventTrigger` won't work here unless you define a (complete) custom template for the `TreeView`.

Instead you could define an `ItemContainerStyle` and invoke the command programmatically:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly MainWindowViewModel _viewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = _viewModel;
    }

    private void TreeViewItem_Expanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) =>
        _viewModel.TreeViewItemExpanded.Execute(null);
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<TreeView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Name="RegistryTreeView" ItemsSource="{Binding Keys}">
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
            <EventSetter Event="Expanded" Handler="TreeViewItem_Expanded" />
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding SubKeys}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

And no, this does *not* break the MVVM pattern as you invoke the very same command from the very same view. MVVM is not about eliminating code. It's about separation of concerns. Whether you invoke the view model command from the code-behind of the view or using an `EventTrigger` and an `InvokeCommandAction` from the XAML markup of the very same view doesn't matter as far as the pattern is concerned.

Comment: Dude, that's so funny you posted this because I did this exact solution last night after finding an old post by you. I was coming on here to update the thread to write about this. and now see that you answered with the pasted solution from that old thread :D